# Controllability of internal subsystem and input-outpout controllability

Tags: matrices, control-theory, linear-control

I am trying to prove that the state equation
$\dot{x} = \begin{bmatrix} A_{11} A_{12}\\A_{21} A_{22}\end{bmatrix}x + \begin{bmatrix} B_{1}\\ 0\end{bmatrix}u$
is controllable if and only if the pair $(A_{22}, A_{21})$ is controllable. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Has $B_1$ full row rank?

Comment: Let's assume it does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can prove this using one of the many equivalent criteria for controllability:

**$(A,B)$ is controllable iff the matrix $[\matrix{A-\lambda I & B}]$ has full row rank for all $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$**

So $(A_{22},A_{21})$ is controllable iff the matrix $[\matrix{A_{22}-\lambda I & A_{21}}]$ has full row rank for all $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$. This means that all the rows of $[\matrix{A_{22}-\lambda I & A_{21}}]$ are linearly independent for all $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$. Equivalently all the rows of $[\matrix{A_{21} & A_{22}-\lambda I}]$ are linearly independent for all $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$ (its an equivalent description of the vectors if you consider a permutation in the numbering of the axes).

Similarly, the full system is controllable iff the matrix $\Big[\matrix{A_{11}-\lambda I & A_{12} & B_1\\A_{21}  & A_{22}-\lambda I & 0}\Big]$ has all its rows linearly independent for all $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$.

Now, if **$B_1$ has full row rank** i.e. its rows are linearly independent and all the rows of $[\matrix{A_{21} & A_{22}-\lambda I}]$ are linearly independent (**$(A_{22},A_{21})$ is controllable**) then it's relatively easy to prove that the rows of the whole matrix would be linearly independent (*due to the appended zeros in $B$*) and therefore the whole system is controllable.

Comment: Thank you very much. So I think that without the assumption that $B_{1}$ has full row rank, the system will be non-controllable even if $(A_{22}, A_{21})$ is controllable, right?

Comment: @Britsk Yes you cannot assume $B_1$ arbitrary. Consider for example $$A=\Bigg[\matrix{1 & 0 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0}\Bigg],\qquad B=\Bigg[\matrix{ 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0}\Bigg]$$ with block dimensions 2 and 1 respectively . The system is not controllable but $(A_{22},A_{21})$ is.